# difference between git branch and git branch -l

Tags: git

In Windows operating system, I clone a git warehouse with Git Bash. I use Git Bash to manipulate `git branch` and `git branch -l`, and find that they all list **local** branch names. When I manipulate `git branch -h`, it lists that `-l, --list   list branch names`, but it doesn't mention that `-l` list local branches.
I'm confused whether their functions are same

Comment: They are the same

Comment: By default `--list` (or if there are no non-option arguments) lists local branches; this is changed if you specify `--remote` or `--all`.

Comment: Technically, a name is a *branch* name if it starts with `refs/heads/` and all such names are local branches. A name is a *remote-tracking* name if it starts with `refs/remotes/`. These name are also local, they're just not *branch* names. Git calls them "remote-tracking branch names" but the word "branch" in here just makes things confusing; I recommend calling them "remote-tracking names" instead. They're your way of remembering some other Git repository's *branch* names (which are local to that other repository).

Comment: Hence "branch" and "local branch" actually mean the same thing, but some people like to stick the word "local" in now and then to remind other people that they don't mean remote-tracking names. Some people use the phrase "remote branch", which is even more confusing: do they mean "a remote-tracking name in my repo, there because repo <url> has a branch name and I'm remembering it" or do they mean "the branch name stored in repo <url>, which doesn't exist yet but I'm about to create" for instance, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git branch` command is used to list, create, or delete branches. By default, it lists the names of all local branches in the repository. For example, running git branch without any additional options will display a list of all local branches:

```
$ git branch
  Yourbranch1
  Yourbranch2
```

The **-l** option is used to limit the list of branches to those that match a specified pattern. For example, running **`git branch -l "feat*"`** will list all branches that start with the prefix "feat"

```
$ git branch -l "feat*"
  feat/feature1
  feat/feature2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `git branch` and `git branch -l` are the same. You are right that in the description of the `-l` option it is not mentioned that it defaults to local branches. However, the documentation of `git branch` begins with the answer to your question:

> If `--list` is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing branches are listed; ... Option `-r` causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option `-a` shows both local and remote branches.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes a table can make it easier to see.

| git branch | Shows local | Shows remote |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | x |  |
| -l or --list | x |  |
| -r or --remote |  | x |
| -a or --all | x | x |

So --list is the default you get if you only type `git branch`.

> DESCRIPTION
>
> If --list is given, or if there are no non-option arguments, existing branches are listed; the current branch will be highlighted in green and marked with an asterisk. Any branches checked out in linked worktrees will be highlighted in cyan and marked with a plus sign. Option -r causes the remote-tracking branches to be listed, and option -a shows both local and remote branches.
>
> [git-scm.com - git-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch/2.28.0)

Answer (score 1):

`git branch --list` *only* lists branches. `git branch` does more (as mentioned `git branch -h` for options). For example,

```
$ git branch
* feature
  main
  temp
  test
$ git branch main
fatal: A branch named 'main' already exists.
$ git branch -l main
  main
$ git branch -l main feature
* feature
  main
```

In a script I can check

```
$ git branch -l main master
* main
```

to see whether a repo is using `main` or `master` and use that result in other commands, for example, `git pull origin main`.